# How to determine the most informative feature in a tree learned by Weka

Tags: artificial-intelligence, data-mining, weka

I used the weka to train a J48 classifier,and it returned a textual representation of tree.
Now if I want to determine which feature is the most informative,how could I proceed?Any idea is welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible that by "the most informative feature" you mean "the feature with the highest [information gain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_in_decision_trees)".

If so, I think the [J48 algorithm constructs decision trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm) such that the first (or highest) node in the decision tree is associated with the feature that has the highest information gain.

If that's correct, then you should be able to look at the top of your tree to determine which feature is the most informative.

Comment: In the Weka-tool, under classify tab, when you build your tree-based model, you can right click and view the tree. It may provide a better view on which features are used to create branches.